# How to move div in row, it's going under the row now

Tags: php, html, css, bootstrap-4

Image of how it looks now : https://ibb.co/C2Gj1FL
I have to make a PDF file with a table made out of divs, I'm using bootstrap, but there is some php code in there also.

```
**Table made with divs**

<div class="split-table-div m-table first-table">
    <div class="row m-header l-table">
        <div class="top-p">
           <p> <?= $property['project_name'] ?></p>
        </div>
            <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 fs-12"><div class="p-1">Nr</div></div> 
            <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 fs-12"><div class="p-1">Benämning</div></div> 
            <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 fs-12"><div class="p-1">Underrättelse</div></div> 
            <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 fs-12"><div class="p-1">Debet form</div></div> 
            <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 fs-12"><div class="p-1">Upparbetat</div></div> 
            <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 fs-12"><div class="p-1">Ej reglerat</div></div> 
            <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 fs-12"><div class="p-1">Godkänt</div></div> 
            <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 fs-12"><div class="p-1">Fakturerat</div></div> 
            <div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 fs-12"><div class="p-1">Riktkostnad +/-</div></div> 
         <div class="row">
            <?php if (isset ($data['previous_json_data'])) :?>
                
            <div class="fs-12 border-left col-sm-1"><div class="p-1">Prognos</div> <?=  $data["created_at2"] ?></div>
            <div class="fs-12 border-right col-sm-1"><div class="p-1">Prognos</div> <?=  $data["created_at"] ?></div>
        
            <?php else : ?>
            <div class="fs-12 col-sm-1" ><div class="p-1">Prognos</div> <?=  $data["created_at"] ?></div>   
            <?php endif; ?>
         
        <div class="fs-12 col-sm-1"><div class="p-1">Status</div></div>
        </div> 
      </div>
    <div class="row m-body">
         //Body div's
    </div>
</div>
```

Image of how it looks now : https://ibb.co/C2Gj1FL

Comment: bootstrap 4 or 5?

Comment: Bootstrap 4 ...

Comment: @IsmailBeg Is the extra `<div class="row">` intentional? I would try taking that out first